# Kotlin Spring could not autowired an @Bean annoted

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm encountering an issue with spring and kotlin :

Here it is :

I have a class MyConfig defined as such

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig

   @Bean
   fun restTemplate(builder: RestTemplateBuilder): RestTemplate =
        builder.build()
```

On the other side I have an other class MyService defined as such

```
@Component
class MyService constructor(private val restTemplate: RestTemplate) {

    fun test() {
        // Use restTemplate
    }
}
```

But all I get is the following message :

```
Description:

Field restTemplate in my.package.MyService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' in your configuration.
```

This issue only occurs with beans defined in @Configuration class (annotated with @Bean) but not with bean declared as @Component or @Service.

I have no such issue with the same kind of architecture in pure-Java.

- I use spring boot 2.0.1
- kotlin 1.2.40
- on java 8

So, have I missed something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `restTemplate` method isn't inside your `MyConfig` class - you've declared an empty class followed by a top level function. You're missing the curly braces that make the function a method inside the class:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   fun restTemplate(builder: RestTemplateBuilder): RestTemplate =
        builder.build()

}
```

Comment: Wow thanks it works, I spent so much time on this.
Looks like I still need to learn the language.

Thanks again  for the fast answer.